# Issue with filtering out rows based on column criterion

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 
VD_1   VD_2   VD_3    VD_4   VD_5  TYPE  VAL
NaN    XX     VV      DD     NaN   ABC   5
NaN    XX     MM     VV      NaN   ABC   6
XX     MM     NaN     NaN    NaN   ABC   6
TT     XX     MM      NaN    NaN   ABC   5
```

I want to keep only those rows that have the first non-NaN value equal to XX and at least two subsequent values that are not equal to NaN neither to XX.

The problem is that `return x` returns `None, None, None`... It only works if I use `return row`, but then the result does not contain the same number of columns as `df`. The code neither excludes columns `TYPE` and `VAL` from the analysis.

```
    def customFilter(x):
        row = x.dropna()
        if (row[0] == 'XX') & (('XX' not in row[1:]) & (len(row[1:]) >= 2)):
            return row
        return np.nan
    df = df.apply(customFilter, axis=1).dropna(how='all', axis=0)

Is there any trick to solve the mentioned issues?
```

UPDATE:

```
# Delete rows that do not start from AG
def calculate_correct_rows(df):
    # Create drop rows
    drop_rows = []
    i = 0
    for index, x in df.iterrows():
        row = x.dropna()
        if (row[0] == 'XX') & (('XX' not in row[1:]) & (len(row[1:]) >= 2)):
            drop_rows.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    return drop_rows

# Drop the rows in list
subset2 = df.filter(like='VD_')
correct_rows = calculate_correct_rows(subset2)
final2 = df.loc[correct_rows,:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a prettier way of doing this, but you could simply perform the filter in two steps instead of one. First, create a list of all rows that do not adhere to the criterion that you mentioned above. Second, use `df.drop(rows)` to drop the rows in the list created in step 1.

Here's the link to `drop`: [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

e.g.

```
def calculate_drop_rows(df):
    # Create drop rows
    drop_rows = []
    i = 0
    for row in df:
        if [condition]:
            drop_rows.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    return drop_rows

# Drop the rows in list
drop_rows = calculate_drop_rows(df)
df = df.drop(drop_rows)
```

Comment: Instead of dropping, how to apply the reverse logic? It's easier for me to use `calculate_correct_rows` that identifies the rows to be maintained.

Comment: You could create a negative of the list by doing something like `keep_rows = [i for i in range(len(df)) if i not in drop_rows]`, and `return keep_rows` instead of `drop_rows`. This is kind of hackish and does not scale well with increasing the `dataframe` size. Without any knowledge of the problem you are working on, it is difficult to tell if this is a valid option for your problem.

Comment: Please see my update.It does not work for some reason. No error, but the result is the same as input.

Comment: You may want to try `.iloc` instead, since `.loc` works by index rather than by position. If the indices are off for whatever reason, they won't match with the `correct_rows` list. Also, check to make sure that `correct_rows` actually has elements in it, if you're not applying your criteria correctly it will still return, but as an empty list, leaving you with the same end result. This may be what's happening for you.

Comment: I had to substitute `i` by `index`. I also had to use `calculate_drop_rows(subset2)` instead of `calculate_drop_rows(df)`, because there was other `df` that apparently was used and that's why I had incorrect results.